# Google Prediction API - dataStoreFactory - setPermissionsToOwnerOnly

Tags: java, authentication, credentials, google-api-java-client

Running the PredicitonSample.java I have everything set with my client_secrets.json and when I run the file with all my credentials I am receiving this error:

```
com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody: C:\Users\100018349\.store\prediction_sample
Jul 01, 2015 4:19:02 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner: C:\Users\100018349\.store\prediction_sample
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at PredictionEngine.authorize(PredictionEngine.java:96)
at PredictionEngine.main(PredictionEngine.java:262)
```

The code for the PredicitonSample.java can be found at this github repo:
https://github.com/gxlzlihao/GooglePredictionAPISample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/prediction/cmdline/PredictionSample.java

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/** Directory to store user credentials. */

private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR =
      new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/analytics_sample");

private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;

dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
```